# How can I loop backwards?

Tags: r, loops

I want to loop through a string 1 time then wait 30 seconds and rerun the loop but this time from last to the first
I am trying to do this like this with no success:

```
for( c in 1:2){
if (c==1) for (i in 1:4){
if (c==2) for (i in 4:1){
print(i)
if(c==1) Sys.Sleep(30)
}
}
```

Comment: So you want your output to look like 1, 4, 3, 2, 1? with a 30s delay between the 1 and 4?

Comment: I want to do something similar to the example I showed so, for the example I wrote it should print 1,2,3,4 then 30s delay and then print 4,3,2,1

Comment: `for(i in 1:4) print(i); Sys.sleep(30); for(i in 4:1) print(i)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for( c in 1:2){
  if(c==1){
    st = 1
    fin = 4
  }else{
    Sys.sleep(30)
    st = 4
    fin = 1
  }
  for (i in st:fin){
      print(i)
  }


}
```

Comment: Great!  Mark as answered please.